# Getting ghostly errors in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

It seems that I'm getting a conflict when trying to make a relationship because of a table I had in my database and then deleted.  The table does not show up in the object explorer but the error says "an exception occured, the new name is already in use as a OBJECT name and would cause a duplicate."  Where does one delete all references to the object, not just the table name.

Comment: Do you have a Synonym in place? Have you checked your sys.tables table to see if there is indeed an entry in there?

Comment: No, I haven't used any synonyms.

Comment: Synonyms aren't objects -- or at least, they're not found in the sys.object table, they get their own subsystem. Which is pretty irritating, when you're trying to figure out what's hitting your data...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably have another object in the database with that name. Run

```
SELECT *
 from sys.objects
 where name = 'YourName'
```

and see what pops up. ("Objects" includes tables, views, procedure, functions, defaults, and a whole lot of other obscure stuff.)

Comment: This did return an object with the conflicting name.  Where do I go about deleting this bad boy to avoid these errors?

Comment: It says it's a table, but it's not showing up with the other tables in the database, why would this be?

Comment: Is it possible that you don't have rights on the table?  Are you logged in as DBO?

Comment: This is my own personal copy of SQL Server on my laptop, so no.  I have been getting these funny errors, though.  I dropped the table and I went to make a database diagram and the table still came up to add to the diagram, what gives with that? I ran the drop table query once and it was successful, ran it again and it failed (object didn't exist).  So why would it still be available to add to the diagram?

Comment: Might be same table name in a different schema? Is it listed in sys.Tables? In sys.objects, what type (or type_desc) of object is it? Outside chance, you might be getting confused with which database you're tlaking with, or even server. (Unlikely... but I just did that 10 minutes ago...)

Comment: Thanks! Your suggested query helped me with this problem.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error every time I ran a script that required deleting a table then renaming another table to the same name immediately after, and came across this recommendation in another forum:

> Leave the schema out of the new table name when renaming:
>
> ```
> sp_RENAME '[schema.OldTableName]' , '[NewTableName]'
> ```

I cannot explain why it works, but it sure saved my code.

(Credit to: Rhomeroo on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/654678f2-313f-4dad-8bd2-1741b01561f3/find-object-sprename-issue )

Answer (score 0):

The solution that helped me:
Prerequisites:
I needed to rename "dbo.spAddUser" into "dbo.sp_AddUser".

What did I do:
Right click on the "dbo.spAddUser" -> Modify.
Copy all that code.
Right click on the "dbo.spAddUser" -> Delete.
Add New Procedure.
Paste copied code and replace: "Alter" to "Create" and correct the procedure's name.
Execute.

Success!